# React Component is rendering infinitely when passing data in between sibling components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My component structure is like this

```
App 

| - TopHeader 

| - Main 

     |- Thread


| - Modal
```

Topheader contains a button for opening a Modal which has a textbox. I'm passing textbox data from Modal->App and changing `newPost` value so that Main could re-render upon detecting change. But this is causing somehow infinite re-rendering. Here is my code for this.
`App`:

```
import "./scss/App.scss";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import TopHeader from "./components/TopHeader";
import Main from "./components/Main";
import RightPan from "./components/RightPan";
import Modal from "./components/Modal";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [shouldModalPopUp, setShouldModalPopUp] = useState(false);
  const [newPost, setNewPost] = useState();
  function handleNewThreadButtonClick() {
    setShouldModalPopUp(true);
  }
  function handleCloseButtonClick() {
    setShouldModalPopUp(false);
  }

  function onPostSubmitHandler(newPost) {
    console.log("before preventDefault");
    setNewPost(newPost);
    handleCloseButtonClick();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* <Sidebar key={1} /> */}
      <TopHeader
        newThreadButtonClickHandler={handleNewThreadButtonClick}
        key={2}
      />
      <Main newPost={newPost} key={3} />
      {/* <RightPan key={4} /> */}
      <Modal
        shouldModalPopUp={shouldModalPopUp}
        handleCloseButtonClick={handleCloseButtonClick}
        onPostSubmitHandler={onPostSubmitHandler}
        key={5}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`Main`

```
import "../scss/App.scss";
import Thread from "./Thread";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Main(props) {
  const [allThreads, setAllThreads] = useState([]);

  function onPostSubmitHandler(newPost) {
    setAllThreads((prevState) => {
      const newList = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < prevState.length; i++) {
        newList.push(prevState[i]);
      }
      newList.push({ post: newPost, id: Math.random() });
      console.log("previous state length: " + prevState.length);
      console.log("new state length: " + newList.length);
      return newList;
    });
  }

  console.log("props received in Main" + JSON.stringify(props));
  function onDeleteHandler(id) {
    console.log("inside ondeletehandler " + id);
    const newList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < allThreads.length; i++) {
      if (allThreads[i].id != id) {
        newList.push(allThreads[i]);
      }
    }
    setAllThreads(newList);
  }

  if (props.newPost) {
    onPostSubmitHandler(props.newPost);
  }

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <span>main</span>
      {allThreads.map((thread) => {
        console.log("appending posts in list");
        console.log(thread.post);
        return (
          <Thread
            post={thread.post}
            id={thread.id}
            onDeleteThread={onDeleteHandler}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

`Modal`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Modal(props) {
  const [post, setPost] = useState("");

  function submitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.onPostSubmitHandler(post);
  }

  function onChangeHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setPost(event.target.value);
  }

  if (props.shouldModalPopUp) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="backdrop" />
        <div className="modal">
          <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <textarea
              id="txtArea"
              className="postTextArea"
              placeholder="please type your post.."
              rows="20"
              cols="80"
              onChange={onChangeHandler}
            />
            <br />
            <br />

            <button
              type="button"
              className="button"
              onClick={props.handleCloseButtonClick}
            >
              close
            </button>
            <button type="submit" className="button">
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return null;
}
export default Modal;
```

`TopHeader`

```
import "../scss/App.scss";

function TopHeader(props) {
  return (
    <div className="topHeader">
      <button
        className="button button--newthread"
        onClick={props.newThreadButtonClickHandler}
      >
        Start a new Thread
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default TopHeader;
```

`Thread`

```
import { useState } from "react/cjs/react.development";
import "../scss/App.scss";
function Thread(props) {
  const [post, setPost] = useState(props.post);
  const [id, setId] = useState(props.id);
  console.log("reached thread method");
  const [isDeleted, setIsDeleted] = useState(false);
  function deleteHandler() {
    setIsDeleted(true);
    props.onDeleteThread(id);
  }
  return (
    <div className="thread">
      {post}
      <button className="button" onClick={deleteHandler}>
        delete
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Thread;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Main`:

```
if (props.newPost) {
    onPostSubmitHandler(props.newPost);
}
```

after you `newPost` is set and passed as a prop to this component, this `if` block will always return `true`.

Due to which, the method `onPostSubmitHandler` will be executed whenever the `Main` component re-renders (i.e., when the props/state of the component changes, in this case `newPost`).

Moreover, you're scheduling a state change in the first line of this method `onPostSubmitHandler` which is causing you infinite re-rendering.

You should use `useEffect` hook instead of the `if` check, with your `props.newPost` variable in the list of dependencies.

You can use object destructuring, to get the `newPost` variable and then pass it in the dependency array like this:

```
const { newPost } = props;

useEffect(() => {
    onPostSubmitHandler(newPost);
}, [newPost]);
```